# Pressing enter on a button causes previous form to process the enter keyup

Tags: vb.net, forms, button

I have an VB.net app with 2 forms.  On form 1 is a combobox that opens form 2 when the enter key is pressed and the combobox has focus.  There is nothing else on form 1.  On form 2, I have an button that closes form 2 but it is not set as form 2's acceptbutton.  There is nothing else on form 2.

Here is the code for form 1:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Test")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim theForm As New Form2
        theForm.ShowDialog()
        theForm.Dispose
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the code for Form 2:

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

The problem I have is that when form 2 is shown and the button has focus, if you press the enter key instead of using the mouse to click on the button, this enter key is not processed by form 2, but the button.click event is fired. And when that event closes form 2 and form 1 resumes, the combobox has focus and processes the enter key and opens form 2.  What I want to happen is that when form 2 is open and the enter key is presses when the button has focus, I want the enter key to be processed by form 2, not by form 1.

I have tried creating the code for the KeyUp, KeyDown, and KeyPressed events on the button, but none of them get called.  I also set KeyPreview to True on form 2 and then added code to handle the keypressed event, but the event does not fire for form 2.  Nor do KeyUp or KeyDown fire for form 2.

Any suggestions?

Note: The sample code I've included is to show the problem I am having.  It is not intended to do anything other than show the problem.  The problem I am having is in a more complex application, but the issue is identical.

-NCGrimbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is for Form1's combobox not to fire while Form2 is open and enter is pressed, you could try this. Simply disable Form1's combobox like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ComboBox1.Enabled = False
        Dim theForm As New Form2
        theForm.ShowDialog()
        theForm.Dispose
        ComboBox1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I setup a project using the code you did, and this fixed the problem so that Form2 doesn't keep opening when enter is pressed. HTH